# jQuery UI Accordion - enable some panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I've got this kind of wizard.
I wish it to be openable only the panels upwards (to turn back) and not those downwards.

For example:
I am filling out the step1, go to step 2, I can not be able to jump to step 4 or 5, but I have to be able to go back to step 1

This is my code:

```
<div id="accordion">
<h3>Step 1</h3>
<div id="img_divisione">
    <a href="">Something</a>
</div>
<h3>Step 2</h3>
<div>
    <a href="">Something</a>
</div>
<h3>Step 3</h3>
<div>
    <a href="">Something</a>
</div>
<h3>Step 4</h3>
<div>
    <a href="">Something</a>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#img_divisione a").click(function() {
   $("#accordion").accordion( "option", "active", 1 );
});
});

$(function() {
   $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        heightStyle: "content"
});
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you explain what your script already does and what is still missing, i.e. where specifically you're having problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the

```
beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {}
```

event of jQuery-ui.

Here is an example from the jQuery UI homepage:

```
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({    
        beforeActivate: function( event, ui ) {
                          if ( ui.newHeader.text() === "Don&#39;tActivateMe" ){
                                 event.preventDefault();        
                           }    
                        }
 });
```

This event can be canceled. So give each of the Panels a class or something to define their order, than check if the ui.newPanel class is greater than the old one. If so, cancel the event.

Be aware that tihs work only from JQuery UI Versions > 1.9.

Hope this helps

Comment: But be aware, that this is not secure. Expierenced user will have access to all the links in your wizard as they are alread in you DOM.